# A <td> containing an <input> has a unwanted minimum height

Tags: html, css

If a td contains an input it appear that browsers force a minimum height of 19px.

```
input{ 
     height: 1px;

}
td{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 1px;
}

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See the demonstration here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Rs2eT/160/

My question is:

1. Why is the td height forced to 19px?
2. How to force a smaller height for the td?

Thank you.

Comment: In which browser you are trying? Because it is appearing fine for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have line height and implied cell padding by default. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rs2eT/161/

```css
input{ 
    height: 1px;
    
}
td{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 1px;
    padding:0; /*there is padding that isn't specified in the declaration*/
    line-height:1px; /*td presumes line height of 1em on all contents */
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type = "text" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `line-height` ?

```
input{ 
    height: 1px;

}
td{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 1px;
    line-height: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

line-height: 1px

should solve your problem. browsers have a default line height.

Answer (score -1):

```
input{ 
    height:19px;
    display:block;
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: @Seb is asking for a way to make the TD shorter. The complaint is that the *apparent* minimum height for a TD containing an input is 19px.

Comment: "minimum height of 19px" is not shorter

Comment: They want it to be shorter. "**browsers force a minimum height of 19px**" means "**I don't want my element to be 19px tall, but I can't seem to make it shorter**". If you read the OP's follow up questions "**Why is the td height forced to 19px?**" and "**How to force a smaller height for the td?**" you can tell that a smaller height is what they are after.